# How to cancel navigation on validation in UWP XAML NavigationView control

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

This is my scenario.

I have a settings page which needs to be validated. I used to do validation in settings page's **OnNavigatingFrom** event. So, a happy days scenario is user makes some changes and navigates away, app validates and saves the changes in the background without user having to do anything. If validation fails I cancel navigation and display a dialog box, so I only bother the user if there is an issue. This has worked well and was simple to implement:

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (!ValidateSettings())
        {
            e.Cancel = true;

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
            await dialog.ShowDialogAsync("Validation Error", "Validation error encountered", "",   "Close");
        }
    }
```

After adding NavigationView control, the above approach no longer works. I am using NavigationView **SelectionChanged** event to perform navigation. Problem is that this event fires BEFORE the child page's OnNavigatingFrom event and navigation cannot be cancelled. What's worse I cannot even save the changes, or rather they are saved after the navigation is complete. So I cannot move some of that logic to the navigation root page.

How can I perform form validation and cancel navigation in NavigationView control?

Please note that I do not want to have a save button because it is a bad user experience. I'd rather bug the user if they make a mistake instead of every time they want to make a change.

I also do not want to validate the changes on every little change because that would also result in bad UX. For example if a user wants to clear all the check boxes before selecting one, this would not be allowed because having all check boxes unchecked is invalid. I hate it when you have to "wrestle" with an app in this way. If I want to clear the form before completing it, that is a valid approach, I don't want to annoy the user with unnecessary validation errors while they are filling up the form.

I use NavigationView control from Microsoft.UI.XAML NuGet v2.4.2

Comment: `NavigationView` is a highly integrated control, and there are not many places that can be customized. I tried setting a variable to judge, reset the selected item of the navigation menu when the `SelectionChanged` event occurs, but even if the selected item can be reset, but the option sign animation has not changed, and can not be posted as a good practice. According to your needs, you can try to use `SplitView` + `Frame` combination to customize your UX.

Comment: To replace NavigationView would be a lot of work! It works great, just misses the navigation cancelling. I ended up adding code to NavView_SelectionChanged to go back to settings if I detect invalid configuration. Not ideal, but it works.  NavView.SelectedItem = (muxc.NavigationViewItem)NavView.SettingsItem;  NavView.Header = "Settings";

Comment: Hi, I made some attempts. In fact, the `ItemInvoked` event occurs before the `SelectionChanged` event, you can try to change the selected item in the `ItemInvoked` event.

Comment: Problem is that I cannot stop SelectionChanged from happening in ItemInvoked. So I thought it is better to do it at the end to avoid race conditions. Any chance for devs to add cancel navigation to these events?

Comment: Hello, you are using WinUI, this is a continuously updated UI framework, you can put forward functional requirements [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/new/choose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to stop navigation by using the property `SelectsOnInvoked` on the `NavigationViewItem`.

Setting this to `False` will stop the `NavigationView` from selecting the `NavigationViewItem` when pressed, but the `ItemInvoked` event is still called, so you can handle your validation there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem.selectsoninvoked?view=winui-2.8